# Implementing CSRF protection in DDD

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, csrf

I'm using PHP and MVC pattern.

I got the functionality but (I'm guessing) it's not within the DDD paradigm.

Currently I got something like the following in my sign up controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->session->setParameter('token', CryptoCharGen::alnum());

    return $this->view->index();
}

public function submit()
{
    $token = array(
        'post'    => $this->request->getParameter('token'),
        'session' => $this->session->getParameter('token')
    );

    // Check if the submission is valid before proceeding (CSRF protection).
    if ($token['post'] === $token['session'] && $token['session']) {
        // other logic
    }

    return $this->view->submit();
}
```

How would CSRF protection be implemented in the domain-driven design pattern?

If anybody could provide me a clear correct example with (pseudo) code, that would be helpful.

Comment: CSRF protection is a pure application side concern, which has nothing to do with business domain.

Comment: Did you try to do something before posting this question here ? Google ? sparkling, big words cannot solve every problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDD has nothing to do with application level security, why don'nt you look at how to have application security in general.

HTTP is only a port and is not part of your domain model.

Have a look at this, and look at where the client UI lives and where the domain model lives.

THe purple outer most ring is where your concern lies and its outside the purview of DDD

[image]

Comment: So that means the way I'm currently implementing it is correct?

Comment: I am not a PHP developer and nor do i really understand the specific security threat you are mentioning here. My general point was about it not coming under the DDD purview and probably asking you to change the tags on this question so that you can get better responses